# How to add query string to httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, .net

I want to add some querystrings to httpwebrequest, however I cannot find any property? I remembered there is a QueryString dictionary which I can use before.

Comment: I don't get you. Just put parameter names and values in the url and execute the request then the page/response will be able to access to the querystring dictionary and consume it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The best way to add a query string is as follows:

```
var targetUri = new Uri("http://www.example.org?queryString=a&b=c");
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(targetUri);

var webRequestResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
```

**Remember:** *If you're using user input to construct the Uri, ensure that you validate it,  escape it and don't trust it.*

Comment: but what if I want to add query string later on..?? e.g `HttpWebRequestObject` is already initialized and I want to add something to Uri for query string @Rob don't forget to tag in comment response

Comment: @ShashwatTripathi, as the `RequestUri` property is read-only and the `Query` property on `Request.Uri` is as well, I suspect the answer is that you can't.

Comment: I could't find a way of extending an existing Request so ended up having to re-create the request from scratch if I wanted to append to it.